# Repeater filled from List<MyClass>, how do I get the class in the webform?

Tags: asp.net, .net, class, repeater, webforms

In my codebehind im filling a repeater with this class:

```
public class Reference
{
    public string PageType;
    public string Url;
    public string Name;
}
```

And this code:

```
var NewReference = new Reference();
NewReference.Name = "Hello World"
TheList.Add(NewReference);
TheRepeater.DataSource = TheList;
TheRepeater.DataBind();
```

How do I get the "Name", "PageType" and "Url" in the webform?

I tried:

```
<%# Eval("Name") %>
```

With no luck...

Comment: i agree with @Dredj in his comment response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As first step - ensure that code which fills in `DataSource` executes (just put a breakpoint).

Try out putting it in label

```xml
<asp:Label runat="server">
    <%# Eval("Name") %>
</asp:Label>
```

Also you can add more formatting if needed

```xml
<asp:Label runat="server">
    <%# String.Format("Name = {0}", Eval("Name")) %> 
</asp:Label>
```

For more details see MSDN [Data-Binding Expressions Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
<%# Container.DataItem.Name %>
```

Where "Name" is the parameter in the object you're referencing.  This is assuming your listing this within the repeater itself.

Comment: No luck... "'object' does not contain a definition for 'Name' and no extension method 'Name' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" Am I missing something? I just used it inside the repeater.

Comment: @theSwede - Try setting the variables as Properties with get/set operators.  I'm not sure, but DataItem may be only looking for those.

Answer (score 0):

if you are going to handle ItemDataBound event,

you could cast dataitem to type Reference and then access your properties

```
var myItem = e.Item.DataItem as Reference;
var youAreLookingFor1 = myItem.Name;
var youAreLookingFor2 = myItem.Url;
var youAreLookingFor3 = myItem.PageType;
```

Otherwise you could access it on the designer

Update!!!!

```
 <%# DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "Name") %>
```

You should also be able to use

```
<%# Eval("propertyName") %>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Well I tried this but got: `'System.EventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'Item' and no extension method 'Item' accepting a first argument of type 'System.EventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"` Am I missing something? Or can I do this without ItemDataBound?

Comment: One more thing.  Make sure that your reference class contains public properties,  not fields.  For example "public string Name {get; set;} "